# Does this negative permeate into the following words or not:"doing absolutely nothing to help alleviate the dreadful, crushing strain"?

Tags: negation

> The edge of paranoia always apparent in Colin's dealings with the world was becoming more pronounced; and meanwhile, Tessa was pretending to be oblivious, doing absolutely **nothing** to help alleviate the dreadful, crushing strain. 
>   (The Casual Vacancy, by J. K. Rowling)

Does the negative sense in ‘*nothing*’ permeate all the rest words that follow? Or does the following to-infinitve is an independent meaning unit that is blocked away from the negative?
If the former is right, I guess you might say to-infinitive modifies *nothing*; if the latter, you might say to-infinitive is an adjunct denoting a purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It permeates.  "...doing absolutely nothing which might alleviate the ... strain".

She took no action that might lessen the strain.